# Exposed date filter that uses "Is between" doesn't include end date

Tags: 8, views

SITUATION:

- Create a view of transactions (a custom entity in my case, but I don't think this is relevant)
- Filter against `Authored on` (which includes both the date and time of creation)
- Expose the filter
- Choose **Operator: Is between**
- Display the view with 10/01/2020 and 10/31/2020 as start and end dates for October
- Note: I'm using the Date Popup module for date entry, which accepts mm/dd/yyyy

Transactions on 10/31/2020 are omitted. How can I include end-date transactions, short of telling users to put 11/01/2020 instead of 10/31/2020 (which is what seems natural to them)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a core bug, as @prkos mentioned, end time is assumed 00:00:00 when it needs to be 23:59:59

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (!empty($form['created']['max'])) {
    // use array_unshift() so custom submit runs before the default submit.
    array_unshift($form['#submit'], '_fix_max_date_submit_function');
  }
}

function _fix_max_date_submit_function($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $date_filter = $form_state->getValue('created');
  if ($date_filter['max']) {
    $date_filter['max'] = $date_filter['max'] . ' 23:59:59';
    $form_state->setValue('created', $date_filter);
  }
}
```

---

#### Alternative solution

You might have to use this solution if you don't like the default `Y-m-d` formatting and rather have a `m/d/Y` input for example. Below I use `Y-m-d`, but you can always change it.

It's a core bug, as @prkos mentioned, end time is assumed 12:00:00 AM when it needs to be 11:59:59 PM

If you enable Views sql query at `/admin/structure/views/settings`
you'll see the query is like:

[image]

So all you have to do is swap the last timestamp with the corrected timestamp that takes 11:59:59 PM into account.

You can do that with [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.2.x), but hold your horses, this hook can only run inside of **mymodule.views_execution.inc** file, so create that file and then you can do

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter()
 */
function mymodule_views_query_alter($view, $query) {
  if (!empty($query->where[1]['conditions'])) {
    foreach ($query->where[1]['conditions'] as $con_key => $con_val) {
      $has_created_date_condition = strpos($con_val['field'], 'node_field_data.created') !== FALSE;
      if (($has_created_date_condition)) {
        // timezone set in /admin/config/regional/settings, will get "Users may set their own time zone" if checked.
        $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();

        $min_date = $view->exposed_data['created']['min'];
        $min_date_obj = DrupalDateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $min_date, $timezone);
        $min_date_timestamp = $min_date_obj->getTimestamp();

        $max_date = $view->exposed_data['created']['max'];
        $fixed_max_date_obj = DrupalDateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s A', $max_date . ' 11:59:59 PM', $timezone);
        $fixed_max_date_timestamp = $fixed_max_date_obj->getTimestamp();

        $query->where[1]['conditions'][$con_key]['field'] = 'node_field_data.created';
        $query->where[1]['conditions'][$con_key]['value'][0] = $min_date_timestamp;
        $query->where[1]['conditions'][$con_key]['value'][1] = $fixed_max_date_timestamp;
        $query->where[1]['conditions'][$con_key]['operator'] = 'BETWEEN';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks (again) @No Sssweat. You seem to be saving me all the time. This solution works perfectly.

Comment: For the benefit of others who may see this, mymodule.views_execution.inc goes in your modules/custom/mymodule directory. Also, because I'm using a custom entity of type transaction, 'node_field_data' is in my case 'transaction_field_data'. Finally, the Filter id for the Authored on filter must be 'created' for this code to work.

Comment: A curiosity question @No Sssweat if you have time: Any idea why modifying the form state in a custom submit function as I explain in my UPDATE above doesn't work? In addition to tacking on the time, I tried simply replacing 2020-10-31 with 2020-11-01 in the submit function as a test. That didn't work either.

Comment: @MarshallMorrise I took your word for it, I guess you must of done something wrong as when I tried, it worked. Perhaps you didn't do `array_unshift` part. I had used `views_query_alter` with D7 to solve this exact same problem, so I decided to stick to that known to work approach, but `form_later` with custom submit sure looks to be a quicker & smarter solution. *[Updated my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/298099/27710)*

Comment: You're absolutely correct @No Sssweat. I failed to use `array_unshift`, so my custom submit was running after the default submit. That's what was keeping it from working. I agree with you that the submit approach is more straightforward than intercepting the views query. I'm using it with the Date Popup module and it seems to work fine, even though user input is mm/dd/yyyy, Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I agree this implementation lacks some UX polishing.

The reason why that day is omitted in your case is because you're not including the time, so **a time of 00:00:00 is assumed**, which is the beginning of the day and most of that day's time will be excluded. The first day also assumes it, but because it's the beginning of the range it includes the whole day.

The solution is to **use the time along with the date**, and give clues to users to orientate them with using Placeholder example values and the Filter field Description:

Empty form:

[image: Views Date Exposed Date Placeholder]

After filling in:

[image: Views Date Exposed filled in Time]

You can come up with better UX Label and Description, I'm just demonstrating a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for this insight, @prkos. I'm using the Date Popup module, which "provides a HTML 5 date popup for all views filters", so dates are entered in mm/dd/yyyy format, with mm, dd, and yyyy each being a separate field. There doesn't appear to be a way to control which date filter fields a popup is applied to; seems to be all or nothing. I'll try some sleuthing to see if I can intercept the second date to tack on 23:59:59 before it gets used by the view. Otherwise, I'll either live with the off-by-a-day problem or ditch the Data Popup module (though I really like it).

Comment: Yes, I like Date Popup too, it provides some nice usability, although it clearly fails in this case with the time missing. But you can try other similar modules that have the time picker option and see if they work for you. Here are some you might try: [Datetime Range Popup](https://www.drupal.org/project/datetime_range_popup), [Date Popup](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_popup), [Bootstrap Materialize DateTime Picker](https://www.drupal.org/project/materialize_datetime_picker), [Date Popup Timepicker](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_popup_timepicker).

Comment: Again, thank you @prkos. Given your explanation, I thought I would add a custom submit function to the views filter to tack on the time, but as I explain in my UPDATE above, it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is also solved by the patch provided in https://www.drupal.org/node/2982968